# changing web root in xampp linux gives error 403 when trying to connect using https

Tags: php, linux, https, xampp

I had a simple website lying inside a folder called test, so I was calling `http://localhost/test` and I'm getting a `Hello World!` message. I was getting also the same message when I call it in `HTTPS` mode: `https://localhost/test`.

The problem is that after I changed my Webroot htdocs directory from `/opt/lampp/htdocs` to `/home/ubuntu/www`, I'm still able to see the hello world message by calling the HTTP link, but when I call the HTTPS link, I'm getting:

```
Access forbidden! 

You don't have permission to access the requested
directory. There is either no index document or the directory is
read-protected. If you think this is a server error, please contact
the webmaster. Error 403
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to modify also the httpd-ssl.conf file which is located in /etc/extra/, and modifying line 86 where we have DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs" to the new directory "/home/ubuntu/www"